# Pandas cannot use datetime in multiindex

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, multi-index

I spend lots of time try to insert data into pandas' DataFrame
but just cannot as I expected.
there are two index:
1. current_time
2. company_name

After I use data.ix[] to insert a row,
the Dataframe create another column (named by the company_name)
Can anyone give me some advice, please.

---

```
import pandas
data=pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Name', 'd1'])
data.set_index(['Date', 'Name'], inplace=True)
now = pandas.datetime.now()
data.ix[now, 'ACompany'] = [1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let pandas know the `now, 'ACompany'` are the levels of the index, you have to use some extra parantheses:

```
data.ix[(now, 'ACompany'), :] = 1
```

By just doing `data.ix[now, 'ACompany']`, pandas will by default try to interpret this as index=now, column='ACompany' (in the sense of `.ix[rows, columns]`)

Further, it is recommended to use `.loc` instead of `.ix` if you want to index solely by the labels.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really helpful.